# What happens if a base method calls an overridden method in VB?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

Consider the following example:

```
Public Class ParentClass
    Public Sub GenerateReport
        Dim Col As Collection
        Col = GetItemCollection()
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Function GetItemCollection() As Collection
        GetItemCollection = New Collection
        GetItemCollection.Add("1")
        GetItemCollection.Add("2")
        GetItemCollection.Add("3")
    End Function
End Class

Public Class ExtendedClass
    Inherits ParentClass

    Public Overrides Function GetItemCollection() As Collection
        GetItemCollection = New Collection
        GetItemCollection.Add("A")
        GetItemCollection.Add("B")
        GetItemCollection.Add("C")
    End Function
End Class

Public Sub Main()
    Dim cls As New ExtendedClass
    cls.GenerateReport()
End Sub
```

When `Main()` calls `cls.GenerateReport()`, is the variable `Col` going to be a collection of numbers or letters? I'm hoping that it will recognize that `cls` is an instance of `ExtendedClass` and call the overridden method and return the letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be a collection of letters as you did override the method. However, where did you declare the `GetItemCollection`? You still need an instance variable.

Comment: GetItemCollection is declared because it's the name of the function and can be used within itself as a collection object.

Comment: I'm not familiar with vb.net. Anyway, the method of the derived class will be called.