# Calling an overridden method from Inheritable class

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, overriding, overloading

Question seems like it should be easy enough, but I can't find the answer in the MSDN documentation. Language is VB.

```
Class A 
     Public Foo: Bar()
     Public Bar: Return "From A"

Class B
   Inherits A
     Public Bar: Returns "From B"
```

How do I set up functions Bar in both classes so when I have an an instance of Class B and call Foo I get "From B"?

Comment: Seems like this is exact dupe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653619/what-happens-if-a-base-method-calls-an-overridden-method-in-vb

But that isn't the behavior I'm experiencing, testing.

Comment: intellisense will pretty much guide you when you enter actual code for the classes

Comment: This question would be improved with actual VB code rather than pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

Yup, resolved. Overrides is required on Class B and Overrideable is required on Class A.

The end code should look something like

```
 Class A
    Public Foo: Bar()
    Public Overrideable Bar: Return "From A"

 Class B
    Public Overrides Bar: Return "From B"
```

Also, the visibility has to match on Bar or else I guess "shadowing" occurs? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/818x9db9(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: [Overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybxdk47f.aspx)  and not my DV

Comment: @Plutonix, I believe Overloads is used when you want different signatures on a method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z71zbeh(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: The pseudocode adds no value to your answer. Please update with code that actually compiles.

Comment: Method Overloading does not require a keyword - it happens based on the method signature (`Bar()` vs `Bar(int32)`).  With inheritance the Overloads keyword almost acts like `Shadows`.   My point was that if you use actual code for the question the IDE will tell you `function Bar shadows an overloadable member in the base class 'A'.  If you want to overload the base method, this method must be declared 'Overloads'`.  When you dont have access to the base class code to mark it Overrideable, Overloads will work.